# Too Many Codes Sent Enter the last code you received or try again later

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, two-factor-authentication

So basically I have two iCloud accounts, one on my devices and the other where I store some of my data, I tried to log in my other iCloud on safari as usual but it said that I received too many codes and should enter the last one I received, the thing is I didn't receive any, so I tried again, it says the same, tried four hours it's still the same, nothing. It's been three days of me trying without any result, I read somewhere on Reddit that the estimated time is increasing with each attempt to receive a code, I contacted Apple support but they couldn't do anything since I don't live in an area where they can call me, so if anyone had this problem and got this solved share your experience here.[image]

Comment: What region of the world is your cellular service? Do you have two SIM active or entered?

Comment: Did you use the same phone number for both accounts?

Comment: @bmike I live in Morocco in North Africa, when this problem occurred I had only one Sim (E-Sim)

Comment: @Allan Yes, the same number, it used to work just fine..

Comment: I proceeded for account recovery and then a phone number’s change in 13 days..

Comment: That is likely the cause of your issues. The way you have one account for devices and the other for files will cause issues with things like handoff and messaging since you can’t be simultaneously signed in to both accounts.